# Why is it that sometimes Swift requires explicitly indicating an argument and sometimes not?

Tags: swift

I am trying to use the following library: https://github.com/peek-travel/swift-currency

One of the ways to use it is to do something like this to mean it is 5 dollars in USD:

```
USD(5.01)
```

I noticed that in one of my subviews, when I do this, I get the error of:

```
Compiling failed: missing argument label 'floatLiteral:' in call
```

Which I can fix by doing `USD(floatLiteral: 5)`, which means the same thing.

Why is it that in some cases in my code I can do `USD(5)` without an error, and in others I have to explicitly state the argument?

Documentation for USD from API reference is here: https://peek-travel.github.io/swift-currency/Structs/USD.html

Comment: Please link the source and documentation for this USD type.

Comment: Updated OP and also here: https://peek-travel.github.io/swift-currency/Structs/USD.html

Comment: I don’t see any initializers that don’t take a keyword label. Do you know where that is?

Comment: I am not sure, the error that came up just showed the message, and adding in floatLiteral: 5 fixed it, though I am trying to understand why.

Comment: Well that part isn’t mysterious at all. There’s an initializer ([`USD.init(floatLiteral:)`](https://peek-travel.github.io/swift-currency/Protocols/CurrencyProtocol.html#/s:s25ExpressibleByFloatLiteralP05floatD0x0cD4TypeQz_tcfc)) that takes a `Double` and requires the `floatLiteral` argument label. That part is no surprise. What *is* surprising is that you’ve had success in other places calling an initializer with no labels, because I don’t see any such initializers mentioned in the docs.

Comment: @Alexander I just created a simple struct conforming to ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral and I can initialize objects of that struct both ways, with and without a label. Not sure how long this has been possible. Not sure if the link works but here it is, https://repl.it/join/rgvtbcmd-joakimdanielson

Comment: If you look at the main page: https://github.com/peek-travel/swift-currency, it has samples when you scroll to the bottom: "let dollars = USD(30.01)". That was what I was expecting, no need to do anything 'floatliteral:' inside of the USD(...). I'm just confused why it let me do that pretty much almost everywhere in my code except for the inside of a Button action.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I actually have no idea why that works. Even stranger, I tried expanding out `Coin(10)` to `Coin.init(10)` (so that I could command click on the `init` part and jump to the declaration), and then got the `Missing argument label 'integerLiteral:' in call` error. Is there some special treatment around `ExpressibleByXLiteral` initializers?

Comment: @Rolando I see those examples, but I don't see any initializers in the documentation which don't have a keyword label, so IDK why those examples work.

Comment: That's the mystery I am trying to solve... would think there is some point I must be missing...

Comment: I think the inconsistency isn't in whether the argument label can be dropped, but rather, in whether you need to use a decimal point, to guarantee that the compiler sees a float literal instead of an integer one. i.e. `USD(5.0)` should always fix the problem, given the current compiler. Confusion sets in because integers literals are *sometimes* allowed. (It would also be nice to know why the argument label can be dropped now, but I suspect it's just a bug.)

Comment: It's probably a bug then. To test, I did attempt to use USD(5.01) just to see if it would fix the problem, and it didn't. Same error. All other places in my code works fine without the floatingLiteral.

Comment: @Jessy `i.e. USD(5.0) should always fix the problem,` why is that? There's still no label-less initializer, from what we can see. `Confusion sets in because integers literals are sometimes allowed.` Huh, I thought that all integer literals are *also* floating point literals.

Comment: While an integer literal *can* be a floating-point literal, they are not the same thing, and are treated differently in the spec. I'm pretty certain the issue here is that you're using SwiftUI, and the types can get incredibly complicated and the compiler can get confused. I'm betting if extract subviews into smaller expressions, it'll work or you'll get clearer errors. Note that this whole approach is pretty dangerous, though they get away with it because they don't implement cryptocurrencies. https://github.com/peek-travel/swift-currency/issues/3

Comment: If you can show an actual example that demonstrates this, we can probably help work through what's happening. But I expect the code has to get really complicated before the problem shows up, and the answer is: make the code less complicated (at least in a single expression).

Comment: @Alexander You misinterpreted my "should". I don't mean it from a moral standpoint.  The documentation and tests for this repo are using parentheses as a substitute for `as` (e.g. `5 as USD`), and it's not idiomatic. The "should" came about from my own testing, but Rolando suggests my testing wasn't rigorous enough, because my hack doesn't work for his case. It works in some, though, and I hate it!

Comment: The case for me that tripped is: having an 'Identifiable' struct that represents a data model "MyDataModel" (one of the properties is of type USD, used in a class of ObservableObject that has a @Published property that is a list "MyDataList" that contains a list of those "MyDataModel" objects. In a subview of content view, there is a button with an action that appends a new hardcoded "MyDataModel" object with the property that is of type USD to be USD(5.01). That's what triggers the error, and I have to do USD(floatLiteral:5.01) for the error to go away.